# Dig from a specific domain shows no answer but normal dig works

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, nameserver, reverse-dns, shared-hosting

I am having an issue with a WHM installation that was done over a week ago. It seems all is good on the WHM side of things but I am having issues with my nameservers I have set up

Whenever I try to change a domains nameservers over to mine it rejects it(ns1.iclixhosting.co.za, ns2.iclixhosting.co.za)

I have called around the different providers and it seems it is **ns2** that is giving the problem

When I run a **dig** command it returns an **A** record

```
dig ns2.iclixhosting.co.za

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.3 <<>> ns2.iclixhosting.co.za
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8738
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns2.iclixhosting.co.za.                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns2.iclixhosting.co.za. 3252    IN      A       164.160.80.20

;; Query time: 304 msec
;; SERVER: 9.9.9.9#53(9.9.9.9)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 17 15:36:59 SAST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

However what they are saying is that they do not pick it up when they try run it through the specific domains we are trying to point to our nameservers

I am not sure what to do further on my side, Thank you for any help in advance

**Edited to add more details**

I am trying to set up ns1 and ns2 as nameservers that other domains can use. I cant point any domains as they say ns2 is not returning with an answer on their servers below is a dig from 8.8.8.8 as I was asked to do in the comments

```
dig @8.8.8.8 ns2.iclixhosting.co.za

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 ns2.iclixhosting.co.za
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60456
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns2.iclixhosting.co.za.                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns2.iclixhosting.co.za. 3599    IN      A       164.160.80.20

;; Query time: 178 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 17 21:11:17 SAST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

As I say I am returning an answer however I cant set ns2 as the nameserver for other domains

**Edited to add more details**

Alright so thanks to Håkan Lindqvist in the comments I ran the command below and got the following results, This is very strange because if I ping the ns2.iclixhosting.co.za I get a response from the server

```
dig @ns2.iclixhosting.co.za heavencloud.co.za +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.3 <<>> @ns2.iclixhosting.co.za heavencloud.co.za +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

**Another Edit**

[dig results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtSxC.png)

Comment: Hi, 

please provide more details about "the problem" ? 

---

it seems that your NS are actualy cloudflare.
You can check it with a : 
`dig NS ns2.iclixhosting.co.za`
NS records are usualy outside the DNS zone in your ISP web interface.

Comment: Your question seems offtopic here as questions in specific panels are offtopic, however in all cases, it is not very clear, what is "normal dig"? What does "it rejects it" mean? Who rejects what with what error message? You should also always use the `@` option to dig to specify which nameserver your query. Otherwise your results depend on the locally configured recursive nameserver, and as such can vary in space and can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: Hi @inattendu and Patrick. I have made the edits as requested. Where should this question be placed Patrick?

Comment: `dig @ns2.iclixhosting.co.za example.com +norec` would be the kind of query that should work if `ns2.iclixhosting.co.za` has a `example.com` zone. The queries in the question just shows that the name `ns2.iclixhosting.co.za` resolves.

Comment: Hey @HåkanLindqvist I just added the results of the comment, It does not seem to be responding saying no server could be reached, What could be the issue?

Comment: `ns1.iclixhosting.co.za` seems to work, but `ns2.iclixhosting.co.za` doesn't answer to my lookup requests too, from two completely distinct places in the world (from Russia and Germany). But it answers to ping requests. Are you sure that it really runs a public name service? I think you better ask questions to that server operator, why is it inaccessible.

Comment: Hey @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for trying your side, Yes I believe it does have a public name service as I don't think ns1 would work if it didn't, I don't 100% know what I should ask them as it appears to be online with no issues due to that ping showing a response. I have updated the question again with another thing I have tried I'm not sure where to start looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like the TCP port 53 is firewalled on NS2

```
nmap -p 53 ns1.iclixhosting.co.za 
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-18 10:50 CET
Nmap scan report for ns1.iclixhosting.co.za (164.160.80.18)
Host is up (0.20s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.82 seconds
```

VS

```
nmap -p 53 ns2.iclixhosting.co.za  -Pn
Host discovery disabled (-Pn). All addresses will be marked 'up' and scan times will be slower.
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-18 10:51 CET
Nmap scan report for ns2.iclixhosting.co.za (164.160.80.20)
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
53/tcp filtered domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.11 seconds
```

could you please list open port on ns2 ?
( ss -ntpl for tcp open port on debian )

Comment: Hi this was 100% the case as it was being blocked by the firewall thank you